# Laravel forgets session after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, nginx

I was able to use this to redirect to another route and pass data to it as well:

```
public function method() {
    $dir = "A";
    $name = "ABC";

    return redirect()->route('catch')->with([
           'dir' => $dir, 
           'name' => $name
     ]);
}

public function catch() {
   dd(Session::has('dir'));
   dd(Session::has('name'));
}
```

Above code was working until today

Then I tried setting session and checking within the method:

```
public function method() {
    Session::put('dir', 'a');
    Session::put('name', 'abc');

    Session::has('dir'); // true

    return redirect()->route('catch');
} 

public function catch() {
    Session::has('dir'); // false
}
```

(this works because of route `Route::get('/catch', ['as' => 'catch', 'uses' => Controller@catch])...`)

*This was working until a second ago and I was messing up with nginx user permissions, then it stopped working*

Comment: seems like You've problems with saving session to files, so try to change `SESSION_DRIVER` to `cookie` in `.env` file.

Comment: @num8er Are files better than cookies? Which folder do I need to give permission for being able to store as files?

Comment: cookies are encrypted by laravel session cookie driver - so don't worry about security,  it save that data encrypted on clientside - so there's no load on Your server's disk io. so these are benefits, bu cookie session has size limits instead of files - so I recommend not to save ton's of records in session. if You insist You can check `storage` or inside of that folder.